# Python scrapy login issue

Tags: python, authentication, scrapy

I am trying to scrape my personal (travel) data from a website that requires me to login to my personal account. I am using the spider below. It's based on a tutorial and worked fine in tests on other websites.

It seems to work fine. However, it doesn't open the logged in page after the `open_in_browser(response)`-line (which I use as a test). Instead it tries to open in my browser:

C:/Users/[user]/AppData/Local/Temp/[filename].html

Strangely, when I put in the wrong password, it acts as you'd expect (opens the login page and showing "wrong password". Also, I am able to scrape data with Scrapy from the public parts of the website without problems.

I am new to scrapy and read a lot of posts on login issues but can't really make sense of what is happening. Any pointers to what is causing this would be hugely appreciated.

*the spider:*

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser


class QuotesSpider(Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    start_urls = ('http://login.ns.nl/login',)

    def parse(self, response):
        token = response.xpath('//*[@name="csrfToken"]/@value').extract_first()
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                         formdata={'csrfToken': token,
                                                   'password': '[password]',
                                                   'email': '[email]'},
                                         meta={'dont_redirect': True, 'handle_httpstatus_list': [302]},
                                         callback=self.scrape_pages)

    def scrape_pages(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)

        # Complete your code here to scrape the pages that you are redirected to after logging in

        # ....
        # ....
```

*and the command window output:*

```
2019-03-21 10:43:50 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.2 started (bot: scrapy_login)
2019-03-21 10:43:50 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.5.0, libxml2 2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.20.0, Twisted 18.9.0, Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018), cryptography 2.4.2, Platform Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
2019-03-21 10:43:50 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'scrapy_login', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'scrapy_login.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['scrapy_login.spiders']}
2019-03-21 10:43:51 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: be649c379dcca999
2019-03-21 10:43:51 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2019-03-21 10:43:52 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2019-03-21 10:43:52 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2019-03-21 10:43:52 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2019-03-21 10:43:52 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-03-21 10:43:52 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-03-21 10:43:52 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-03-21 10:43:52 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (307) to <GET https://login.ns.nl> from <GET http://login.ns.nl/robots.txt>
2019-03-21 10:43:52 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://login.ns.nl> (referer: None)
2019-03-21 10:43:52 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (307) to <GET https://login.ns.nl> from <GET http://login.ns.nl/login>
2019-03-21 10:43:52 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://login.ns.nl> (referer: None)
2019-03-21 10:43:53 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://login.ns.nl/sessions/new> from <POST https://login.ns.nl/login>
2019-03-21 10:43:53 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.ns.nl/mijnns> from <GET https://login.ns.nl/sessions/new>
2019-03-21 10:43:54 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.ns.nl/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2019-03-21 10:43:54 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.ns.nl/mijnns> (referer: https://login.ns.nl)
2019-03-21 10:43:54 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-03-21 10:43:54 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 2189,
 'downloader/request_count': 8,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 7,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 35958,
 'downloader/response_count': 8,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 4,
 'downloader/response_status_count/302': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/307': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 21, 9, 43, 54, 867531),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 9,
 'log_count/INFO': 8,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 4,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 5,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 5,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 5,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 5,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 21, 9, 43, 52, 233556)}
2019-03-21 10:43:54 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Try adding `meta={'dont_redirect': True, 'handle_httpstatus_list': [302]}` in your FormRequest.from_response request. Then in the callback, if you try fetching any other url (your profile for example) you should be logged in.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Sewake !

I have updated the code in the original post. 

I am afraid I do not completely follow the second part though. How would I fetch another url? In this case it would be "https://www.ns.nl/mijnns#/dashboard" 

(sorry for the probably dumb questions. I am completely new to Python / Scrapy, coming from only using Rstudio a bit).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, when you use `open_in_browser` method you expect Scrapy to open a new tab with the real url in the browser adress bar ? This method is only used for debugging spiders so it will always try to open a file (which is the response downloaded by Scrapy), even when you enter a wrong password

Comment: You are correct @Sewake Using it with other test websites it indeed opened the user page (the page you get directed to after logging in) in my chrome browser. Yet, with this page that is not the case. What makes it more confusing is that if I enter the wrong password in the spider, it 'correctly' opens the login page in the browser, displaying the same message you would get after manually entering the wrong password. This makes me think that the issue is not the login itself (that seems to work fine), but the (new) url that is being used for the follow-up action (scraping, opening the page)

Comment: Just to clarify: opening the page in my browser is not the purpose of this project. I simply used it as a test so far to see if the login was succesful. The goal is to scrape the travel data from the user dashboard you are directed to after logging in.

Comment: @tom_keys I don't have an account on this site so I couldn't check this further. But one thing I noticed, the site is also using the status code 307 to do a redirect:
`DEBUG: Redirecting (307) to <GET https://login.ns.nl> from <GET http://login.ns.nl/login>`
So you can try to put this in the `handle_httpstatus_list` on the meta dict.
Personally I would let Scrapy handle the redirects first and see what happens.
You can also use inspect_response which allows you to use open_in_browser:
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html#invoking-the-shell-from-spiders-to-inspect-responses

Comment: @LuizRodriguesdaSilva Thanks for your response! Unfortunately adding 307 had no effect. 

I'm very new to scrapy and a bit out of my depth here. I am going to read up on this and do some experiments and report back.